# Android notification not showing

Tags: android, android-notifications

This is the weirdest thing I ever met in Android development. I want to show a simple notification from a service, the notification is successfully shown when I run it on a virtual device in android studio, but when I run it on my own phone the notification doesn't show at all.

[Notification shows on AVD test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fbm8.png)

I make sure that the notification is allowed on my phone, I can even see the channel information
on the notification settings page, which means the channel is successfully built, but the notification just does not show.

[Channel information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrcZc.jpg)

[No notification on phone test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECVVu.jpg)

The following is my code:

```
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText("test")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(001, builder.build());
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

By the way, the AVD I used is in API level 29 and my phone is a Huawei phone on HarmonyOS 2.0 but still API level 29.

Comment: How do you trigger the notification? Did you make sure(with the debugger) that the above code is actually executed on your Huawei phone?

Comment: do you see anything suspicious in logcat?

Comment: I think I found the problem, the logcat says "Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(icon=Icon(typ=RESOURCE pkg=com.example.phonemonitor id=0x7f08008b) visible user=0", I'm still searching for the way to solve it I think it is the icon I used is not suitable for my own phone.